# Order duplication on magento2

Tags: sales-order, magento2.1.5, aws, place-order

On March 22nd, 2018 we went for a Sale on our Magento 2.1.5 live site deployed on an AWS server m4.4xlarge. On 12am sale started with 1500 online visitors and in the next 3 peak hours, there are some duplicate orders. The amount, items, billing/shipping everything is same even the quote_id (verified from database table sales_order) is same. Entity_id and increment_id is changed only.

We never face this same issue before Sale or after Sale, even for the next three days of sale there is no such duplicate issue.

**Duplicate orders are only for guests with cash_on_delivery payment method.**

I checked the loader issue but that is not the case since "Place Order" button gets disable and full-page loader appears as soon as you click the button for the first time. I'm not able to replicate the issue. Any help?

Comment: have you resolved the issue, What what the solution ?

Comment: @ArunKarnawat no we were not able to found the issue.

Comment: for 7 months! I'm having the same issue. will back if I found a solution

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: @Sarvagya since we were not able to replicate the issue, we used the workaround of marking/labeling the repeated orders in the grid.

Comment: @saiid I am thinking about doing 2 things together 1.) Generating locks on quote_id so we don't have the duplicate orders generated at the same time. 2.) To check order' quote_id before  order is placed and only let it placed if the converted quote is not present in the db with same quote_id.
I am not sure if it is the correct solution but it can be a workaround. I hope so.

Comment: It's really a huge bug but as it's doesn't occur every time order is placed. It's very difficult to fix it properly or report is as a bug to magento.

Comment: Yes, you can apply some checks on quote_id to stop the order from duplication. Since I was not able to replicate the issue after it happened the first time, it is difficult to debug really.

Comment: Does anyone found the solution for the above issue?